# An interesting qn came in my mind related to outer measure of the cartesian product of A and B??

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

So here are the questions came in my mind, but I could not answer each of them..

1. If $A$ and $B$ are two subsets of $\Bbb{R}$ then $\lambda_2^*(A×B)=\lambda_1^*(A) \lambda_1^*(B)$?? (If not the case, then what types of counter we should look for?) where $\lambda_2^*(A)$ is Lebesgue outer measure of any subset $A$ in $\Bbb{R}^2$ and $\lambda_1^*(A)$ is Lebesgue outer measure of any subset $A$ in $\Bbb{R}$. (I can only prove that $\lambda_2^*(A×B) \leq \lambda_1^*(A) \lambda_1^*(B)$.)
2. And now if the above does not hold always, then in what condition or restriction we should give two the sets $A$ and $B$ such that the above equality hold, and how to prove it?? (Not just $A$ and $B$ are measurable; then it holds. I want to look for some general fact.)

Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please use MathJax for formatting, proper punctuation, and only commonly known abbreviations. I've edited your post for you this time, and you can click the "Edit" link to see how the MathJax parts are done.

Comment: @aschepler thanks..

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy sir look at this and can you tell me the source??

Comment: I googled "outer measure of product" and found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1180475/product-of-outer-measure-equals-outer-measure-of-product)